# Kafka Number of messages in a topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I need the number of messages in a kafka topic stored.
This is not concerned with whether any consumer has consumed the messages or not.

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --topic test-topic
```

The above gives the offset number for the topic?

Is the above equal to the number of messages currently stored in the kafka topic?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. The numbers you got only refers to the current max offsets of all the topic partitions. Message count also depends on the partitions' beginning offsets for that topic.

You could run

`kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --topic test-topic --time -1`

and

`kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 --topic test-topic --time -2`

respectively, and calculate the message count for each partition by subtracting beginningOffsets from endOffsets, then sum them up to get the total record count for that topic.

Comment: This is not true for compacted topics

Comment: When I compact do we lose any data. WHat is the right way to cross verify the compaction applied successfully without any data loss.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,this is equal to number of messages if earliest offset is equal to zero.If earliest offset is not equal to zero ,you need to calculate the difference and then sum per partition.

Comment: This is not true for compacted topics

Answer (score 0):

The above gives the offset number for the topic?
**Yes it gives the current max offset**

Is the above equal to the number of messages currently stored in the kafka topic?
**No, it's not the number of messages in the kafka as after retention period messages will be deleted from topic so offset != count of messages**

To get number of messages in kafka

```
    brokers="<broker1:port>"
topic=<topic-name>
sum_1=$(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list $brokers --topic $topic --time -1 | grep -e ':[[:digit:]]*:' | awk -F  ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}')
sum_2=$(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list $brokers --topic $topic --time -2 | grep -e ':[[:digit:]]*:' | awk -F  ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}')
echo "Number of records in topic ${topic}: "$((sum_1 - sum_2))
```

where option --time -1 => current max offset & --time -2 is current min offset