# Counting Messages in Kafka Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I am trying to understand how to keep track of message ingestion with Kafka.

The workflow we follow right now is purging all the messages in the topics, and then we re-ingest with code changes. I need to know how successful those code changes are. In current state I am using Kafka Tool and manually refreshing the Total number of Messages, and keeping my results in a csv, which I know is not sustainable long term.

What are your recommendations on automating fetching the counts of messages in Kafka Topics? Ideally I would like to hit the topic on a minute by minute frequency and get the counts, as well as windows of time like 1 day etc.

*I cannot use KSQL because of stability issues we are having.

Answer (score 3):

Counts on messages is also dependent on the log compaction.

---

For example, you might observe "strange results" when log compaction is effective for one topic. 
Say you have a topic `myTopic` that has 100 messages in total. Assuming that you have a log compaction policy that takes effect now, the count might be reduced to say 20 messages because older messages have been compacted.

---

In order to get the message count per partition, you can use the following command:

```
kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
  --broker-list localhost:9092 \
  --topic myTopic
```

and the result would be something similar to the one below (assuming `myTopic` has 3 partitions):

```
myTopic:2:34 
myTopic:1:33 
myTopic:0:33
```

Alternatively, for overall sum you can use this one:

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
  --broker-list localhost:2181 \
  --topic myTopic \
  --time -1 \
  --offsets 1 \
  | awk -F  ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}'
```

You might also find some [Kafka Monitoring Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276785/monitoring-ui-for-apache-kafka-kafka-manager-vs-kafka-monitor/49292872#49292872) useful in this context. More precisely, [`CMAK`](https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK) (aka `kafka-manager`) has one section in metrics about *Summed Recent Offsets*

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63191575/163585

To get number of messages in kafka:

```
brokers="<broker1:port>"
topic=<topic-name>
sum_1=$(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list $brokers --topic $topic --time -1 | grep -e ':[[:digit:]]*:' | awk -F  ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}')
sum_2=$(/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list $brokers --topic $topic --time -2 | grep -e ':[[:digit:]]*:' | awk -F  ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}')
echo "Number of records in topic ${topic}: "$((sum_1 - sum_2))
```

where option `--time -1` => current max offset & `--time -2` is current min offset.

Number of messages in the kafka as after retention period messages will be deleted from topic so offset != count of messages**

Answer (score 0):

If you have metrics enabled. This is how you do in prometheus

```
sum(kafka_topic_partition_current_offset{topic="mytopic"})- sum(kafka_topic_partition_oldest_offset{topic="mytopic"})
```